# jQuery getJSON Never Calls Success Function When Successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, http-headers

I am using jQuery to retrieve json data from a server.  The server responds with a json-encoded object.  The problem is, after the server responds, my success function does not get called.

Here is my request:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.getJSON('?getAvailableRoom', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert("Success!"); // doesn't happen
  });
});
```

Here is the response from the server:

```
Response Headers
Content-Type        application/json
Date                Mon, 09 Jul 2012 20:02:10 GMT
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Via                 1.1 teleproxy01 (NetCache NetApp/6.0.3P2D5)

Request Headers
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Host    XXXXX
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Referer XXXXX
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest

Response
{'id':'AsuRC'}
```

Comment: Whats the status code of the response?

Comment: @alexn: I'm assuming 200 since there is a JSON response.

Comment: @Rocket you can send a body for all status codes.

Comment: @alexn I assume it's 200; FireBug isn't giving me a response code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid.

It should be:

```
Response
{"id":"AsuRC"}
```

Comment: Yes, JSON requires double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Oh... wow.  I assume that's not something that's done on my end, and that the server returned single quotes?

Comment: The server returned single quotes, yes.

Comment: @Tanaki: The server should return double quotes.  Where is the JSON coming from?

Comment: The call on the server side was written by someone on another team.
I'll let them know.

Comment: @Tanaki: You can try to parse it a different way.  Instead of `$.getJSON`, try: `$.get('?getAvailableRoom', function(data){ var obj = eval('('+data+')'); }, 'text');`

Comment: @Rocket Thanks; I'll keep that for reference, but I feel like yelling today.

Comment: It's usually better to fix the problem at the source anyway.